# Scatterplot, python: How to use different color when another variable then the plotted variable is 0 or 1

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter-plot

(matplotlib, python 2.7)

Trying to make a scatterplot for x and y:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The code for a scatterplot would of course be:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

However, given the z list below, I want the color for y to be black when z = 0 and orange when z = 1.

```
z = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

What should I do? Tried google and other stackoverflow posts, but no succes so far..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just need to specify the color using the [`c` keyword argument](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter):

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=['k' if zz == 0 else 'orange' for zz in z])
```

Of course, you could get even fancier with a mapping that converts color values to a color code for matplotlib:

```
color_map = {
    0: 'k',
    1: 'orange
}
plt.scatter(x, y, c=[color_map.get(v, 'cyan') for v in z])
```

The advantage here is clear -- It's much easier to add more colors to the plot.

Comment: Thanks all! Solved it.